# Rails render doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, render

I'm trying to return a json value from rails controller, but strangely it doesn't work and always wants html format. Here's my controller method:

```
  def result
        @command = params[:output]
        @result = []
        IO.popen("free -m") { |f| f.each { |e| @result << e } }
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
        @result << "No command found"

    render json: @result.to_json
  end
```

After I try to reach to this page, I get this kind of error:
Processing by MainController#result as HTML

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template main/result, application/result with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/vyivrain/Documents/RubyProjects/Diploma/app/views"
```

Somewhy it only wants html format. I also tried to do respond_to or render nothing or render plain, but it gives the same result. By the way my rails version is 4.1.5. So it's kinda strange. Thx for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
  def result
    begin
        @command = params[:output]
        @result = []
        IO.popen("free -m") { |f| f.each { |e| @result << e } }
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
        @result << "No command found"
    end

    render json: @result.to_json
  end
```

Comment: Yeap, you're right, just a forgettable memory, that rescue covers block of code if you specify begin/end, otherwise covers whole method. Thx

Answer (score 0):

try to specify `:remote => true` when you click on the link that redirects to `result` action